How to write a query to fetch table columns and json column array elements as columns in the same row in Postgres
I have following data in my table:

I need to develop a SELECT statement which returns the output as follows:

Following is the script to create table and generate above data:
CREATE TABLE employees.employee_data (
    emp_id              varchar(50)  PRIMARY KEY,
    associations        JSONB NOT NULL default '{}'::jsonb
);

INSERT INTO employees.employee_data
(emp_id, associations)
VALUES('1001', '{
                              "group_tags": [
                                {
                                  "orgId": "XYZCompany",
                                  "locationId": "Location01"
                                },
                                {
                                  "orgId": "XYZCompany",
                                  "locationId": "Location02"
                                }                               
                              ]
                            }'::jsonb);
                            

INSERT INTO employees.employee_data
(emp_id, associations)
VALUES('1002', '{
                              "group_tags": [
                                {
                                  "orgId": "ABCCompany",
                                  "locationId": "Location03"
                                },
                                {
                                  "orgId": "ABCCompany",
                                  "locationId": "Location04"
                                }                               
                              ]
                            }'::jsonb);

Can anyone help me out on this?

Provide statements for CREATE and INSERT data so that I can run them through DB Fiddle.

The script is here:  https://qtext.io/021a

Just do a query like this
select emp_id , jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_array(associations , '$.group_tags[*].orgId')) orgId, 
jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_array(associations , '$.group_tags[*].locationId')) locationId
from employees.employee_data;

A version returning text instead of JSON values
select emp_id, 
jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(associations , '$.group_tags[*].orgId')) orgId, 
jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(associations , '$.group_tags[*].locationId')) locationId
from employees.employee_data;

Fiddle to test

Awesome.  But, the org/location columns are returning values in double quotes (I guess it is json string).  How to get those values in normal way (like emp_id)?

It's a residue from the JSON data type but can be removed, I'll include a version removing double quotes.

No need for a regex_replace, just use the json functions to return text instead of json.

@FrankHeikens, I am new to Postgres.  Do you mind modifying above query with json function as you mentioned?  Curious to learn new ways :)

@FrankHeikens you're right, it's possible using just jsonb functions.

Just use the function jsonb_array_elements() to get all array elements and extract the content you need:
SELECT emp_id
    ,   content->>'orgId'
    ,   content->>'locationId'
FROM employees.employee_data
    , jsonb_array_elements(associations->'group_tags') jae(content);

The operator ->> returns text from a json element, while -> returns json.
